# Need help in getting Address output in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-2.0

I m facing the below problem to fetch the Address, my requirement is to get the Current and Permanent Address seperately based on peci:Usage_Behavior_ID but i m not able to fetch any help on this is much appreciated.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Summary>
        <peci:Integration_Event>ca000e0bfc7d10056cba8e3f90580000</peci:Integration_Event>
        <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2022-07-12T11:50:39.796-07:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>CUSTOM_ORGANIZATION-6-121</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>India Payroll</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Code>INDPAY</peci:Payroll_Company_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Group_ID>PG_India_Pay_Group</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Name>India Pay Group</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Country>IN</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Code/>
        <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2022-07-01-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
        <peci:Pay_Period_End>2022-07-31-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_End>
        <peci:Updated_From>2022-07-11T05:40:07.000-07:00</peci:Updated_From>
        <peci:Updated_To>2022-07-12T11:50:39.796-07:00</peci:Updated_To>
        <peci:Effective_From>2022-07-01-07:00</peci:Effective_From>
        <peci:Effective_To>2022-07-31-07:00</peci:Effective_To>
        <peci:Change_Detection>Include only changes entered since the last successful
            run.</peci:Change_Detection>
        <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
        <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
        <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
        <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>
        <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
    </peci:Summary>
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:WID>034e29aefd0e1012e7328dbe7bd30000</peci:WID>
            <peci:Employee_ID>100879</peci:Employee_ID>
            <peci:Name>Test India Employee</peci:Name>
        </peci:Worker_Summary>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-12T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-12T11:49:35.683-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
                        <peci:Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Address>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Test 123</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:City>Bangalore</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>125447</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>IN</peci:Country>
                    <peci:State_Province>Karnataka</peci:State_Province>
                    <peci:Usage>
                        <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>Permanent</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                    </peci:Usage>
                </peci:Address>
                <peci:Address peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>1334</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:Address_Line_2>vinay</peci:Address_Line_2>
                    <peci:City>chennai</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>600045</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>IN</peci:Country>
                    <peci:State_Province>Tamil Nadu</peci:State_Province>
                    <peci:Usage>
                        <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>Current</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                    </peci:Usage>
                </peci:Address>
                            </peci:Person_Communication>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

In the below scenario for address section if peci:Usage_Behavior_ID ='Permanent' Then only address of Permament should come
Output should be

```
<Address_Line_1>Test 123</Address_Line_1>
<City>Bangalore</City>
<Postal_Code>125447</Postal_Code>
<Country>IN</Country>
<State_Province>Karnataka</State_Province>
```

if peci:Usage_Behavior_ID ='Current'  Then only address of Current should come

Sample output

```
<Address_Line_1>1334<Address_Line_1>
<Address_Line_2>vinay<Address_Line_2>
<City>chennai</City>
<Postal_Code>600045</Postal_Code>
<Country>IN</Country>
<State_Province>Tamil Nadu</State_Province>
```

I tried but the address is getting overlapped. Please provide a solution this

````
    <xsl:choose> 
                    <xsl:when test="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address/peci:Usage/peci:Usage_Behavior_ID ='Current'">
                        
            <!--Current Flat/House/Wing Number - -->
            <Current_Flat_House_Wing_Number xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:Address_Line_1"/>
            </Current_Flat_House_Wing_Number>

            <!--Current Street/Locality/Area - -->
            <Current_Street_Locality_Area xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:Address_Line_1"/>
            </Current_Street_Locality_Area>

            <!--Current Landmark - -->
            <Current_Landmark xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:Address_Line_1"/>
            </Current_Landmark>

            <!--Current Pincode - -->
            <Current_Pincode xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:Postal_Code"/>
            </Current_Pincode>

            <!--Current Country - -->
            <Current_Country xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:Country"/>
            </Current_Country>

            <!--Current State - -->
            <Current_State xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:State_Province"/>
            </Current_State>

            <!--Current City - -->
            <Current_City xtt:quotes="always">
                <xsl:value-of select="peci:Person_Communication/peci:Address[peci:Usage_Type='HOME']/peci:City"/>
            </Current_City>
                    </xsl:when>
                    
                </xsl:choose>
    ```
The output i got was repeating
````

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: i posted the code which i tried but it was looping into both the Usage id behaviour

Comment: This is quite useless. Please post complete, executable code, not snippets taken out of context. See: [mcve].

Comment: Same for the expected output: post the complete expected result.

Comment: What you didnt understand here in the xml , I want to output the Permanent and Current address seperately from the xml . I have given the source and output expected. The xml source is huge I cant post the whole code it does not allow here ,

Comment: Then remove the parts that are irrelevant to the problem - again, see: [mcve].

Comment: In your example both criteria are met: there is Permanent and a Current address. Which one should be used?